# Basic Java - Coding in text editor, cannot create new object from a different file although they're in the same package "Cannot find symbol"

Tags: java, cannot-find-symbol

This code compiles fine:

Person.java

```
package people;

class Person{
    private String name;
    private int age;

public Person(String name, int age){
    this.name = name;
    this.age = age;

}

public String getName(){
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name){
    this.name = name;
}

public int getAge(){
    return age;
}

public void setAge(int age){
    this.age = age;
}

}
```

This does not:

controller.java

```
package people;
public class controller{
    public static void main (String[] args){

        Person mark = new Person();
        mark.setName("Mark");
        mark.setAge(24);

    }
}
```

I'm getting this compile error:

```
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_66\classes\controller.java:7: error: cannot find symbol
        Person mark = new Person();
        ^
  symbol:   class Person
  location: class controller
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_66\classes\controller.java:7: error: cannot find symbol
        Person mark = new Person();
                          ^
  symbol:   class Person
  location: class controller
```

I'm researched this quite a bit and can't seem to figure it out. Am I trying to instantiate the object incorrectly in my controller.java file? Thanks.

Comment: have you set classpath correct in your compile? You need to set it to include location of folder people including compiled Person.class

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your class `Person` has a constructor that takes two parameters, a `String` and an `int`. However, you are trying to create a `Person` object using a constructor that takes no parameters:

```
Person mark = new Person();
```

You need to pass the parameters to the constructor:

```
Person mark = new Person("Mark", 24);
```

Ofcourse you don't need to call the `set...()` methods anymore after that.

The Java compiler automatically creates a constructor without parameters in a class, but only if you didn't explicitly add any constructor at all in your class.

Comment: I tried that as well, I get the same "cannot find symbol" error.

Comment: What I described is definititely one thing you'll have to fix. If you still get the error, then there's more that's incorrect. One thing is: if you put classes in a package, they must be in a directory that matches the package structure. Your files must be in a dir named `people`. The commands you quoted show that you didn't do this.

Comment: @Jasper is right! Fix your code first! Remove your  explicit constructor from Person.java end then compile using  `javac  Person.java controller.java`

Answer (score 0):

Run compiler from sources root. You must be in folder that contains "people" folder matching packager name.

Example. Java files in "D:\2\people", if current folder is "D:\2\people" and you run

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.8.0_60\bin\javac.exe" controller.java
```

then you will get error that you describe.

But if you change current folder to "D:\2" and run

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.8.0_60\bin\javac.exe" people\controller.java
```

all will be compiled. Don't forget to fix you constructors.

Comment: I have the directory that contains the 'people' folder in my classpath, do I also need to add the 'people' folder to my classpath?